# Maven Findbugs plugin not executing with mvn site command

Tags: maven, findbugs, html-rendering, maven-site-plugin

I'm trying to get Findbugs working with an existing/mature Maven project.

I added the following to the `<plugins>` tag in my `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.5</version>
  <configuration>
    <effort>Max</effort>
    <threshold>Low</threshold>
    <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I then see that the Findbugs plugin runs when you run `mvn site`. Since the build invocation for my project is aleady:

```
mvn clean jacoco:prepare-agent test site jxr:jxr -Dkey1=123 -Dkey2=456 -Denvironment=DEV
```

...I just run it like I normally do. The build succeeds and I go to my normal site summary in my browser:

[image]

No where from here can I find any "Findbugs" reports or anything that mentions Findbugs at all. When I do a grep for Findbugs (`grep -rl "findbugs" .`) I do see that many of my `./target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml` files have the term "*findbugs*" mentioned in them.

Worth mentioning that I do *not* see a `target/site/findbugs.html` file after the successful build...

Any ideas as to where I can find HTML Findbugs output under my Site summary (or anywhere else)? Looking for a nice HTML report showing which (if any) Findbugs checks failed.

Comment: Just a thought: maybe I don't have a config file (I never specified one in the configs anywhere) and maybe Findbugs doesn't execute or fall back to a default file if none is provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the FindBugs plugin in the `<plugins>` section of the `<reporting>` section of your `pom.xml`:

```
<project>
  ...
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
  ...
</project>
```

The question just states `<plugins>`, not sure if that could be the issue.

Comment: Yep that was it, thanks @Juan! I'll give you the green check and award you the bounty in 2 hrs as soon as SO allows me!